# Deducted values in one list with values in another list with R

Tags: r, list

I have two lists `A1` and `A2`, I need to deduct every values in `A1` with every values in `A2`. Like `A1$aa[1] - A2$aa[1]`.

I simply tried `A1-A2` but obviously it is not the correct way.

How can I compute A1-A2?

```
A1 <- list (aa = list(a = data.frame(matrix(1:10,10,15)),
                      b = data.frame(matrix(1:10,10,15))),
            bb = list(a = data.frame(matrix(1:10,10,15)),
                      b = data.frame(matrix(1:10,10,15))))

A2 <- list (aa = list(a = data.frame(matrix(1:10,10,15)),
                      b = data.frame(matrix(1:10,10,15))),
            bb = list(a = data.frame(matrix(1:10,10,15)),
                      b = data.frame(matrix(1:10,10,15))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `map2`

```
library(purrr)
map2(A1, A2, ~ map2(.x, .y, `-`))
```

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I tried map2 for both my example and my real data, but they both returned a list with 'NULL'.

Comment: @Shepard your data is a list of list.  I updated. it should work

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is what you are after

```
> Map("-",A1,A2)
$a
  x y
1 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
4 0 0
5 0 0
6 0 0
7 0 0

$b
  x y
1 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
4 0 0
5 0 0
6 0 0
7 0 0
```

Comment: I made the example with the wrong data type. So sorry for wasting your time. I have tried your suggestion with the new example I made and this is the error message `Error in .Primitive("-")(dots[[1L]][[1L]], dots[[2L]][[1L]]) : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Comment: I get the same error.  May be it is because of nested `Map(function(x, y) Map(`-`, x, y), A1, A2)`

Answer (score 0):

if you want a list as a result, try this:

```r
lapply(1:2, function(i) A1[[i]] - A2[[i]])
```

Comment: I got this error message still `non-numeric argument to binary operator`. Isn't it in the lapply `A1[[i]] - A2[[i]]` the same meaning as `A1-A2`?

Comment: I tried the code with your dataset and it works for me. `A1[[i]] - A2[[i]]` acts directly on the list arguments (in your case dataframe), while `A1 - A2` is an operation between lists not allowed. Try rerun your sample code and `lapply`

Comment: I am so sorry. I made the example with not exactly the same data type. I have updated my question. So sorry for wasting your time.